# Display a UAC Shield Icon next to a WPF Button?

Tags: c#, wpf

Microsoft requires a UAC Shield Icon next to buttons and list entries that will open a UAC verification prompt. How do I get this Icon next to my WPF Button?

[image: Image of UAC Button]

I've been searching the web for more than an hour now but I was unable to find a way of adding this shield icon to an WPF Button.

I have a WPF Form using a normal WPF Button but most of the scripts I was able to find didn't worked for me - mostly because my Buttons don't have a `FlatStyle` or `Handle` property (I think the WinForms-Buttons have these properties)

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community with a .NET Framework 3.5 Application using WPF

I hope you guys are able to help me. Have a nice day

Comment: use a custom wpf style. add an image to the button and your text.

Comment: See [here](http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/uac-shield-icon-in-wpf) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2006/10/16/stockicons-for-windows-presentation-framework.aspx).

Comment: I can't get it to work. I tried [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yvesdolc/archive/2006/10/16/stockicons-for-windows-presentation-framework.aspx) approach but my IDE is unable to find clr-namespace:VistaBridge.UI and thus the image embeds doesn't work

Comment: @farhan-anam the Icon looks diffrent on diffrent Windows version. This is why Windows is supposed to provide the image - That's at least how I understand it

Comment: I thought that you just wanted to inform the user that the button has something to do with UAC. But that's not the case and I'm afraid I can't help. Sorry.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The actual Windows icon for running version of windows is supplied via the Win32 API.  I'm not aware of any functions in .NET to directly retrieve it, however it can be accessed via p/invoke on `user32.dll`.  Details can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18509/Add-a-UAC-shield-to-a-button-when-elevation-is-req).  Adjustments will need to be made for WPF, as the linked code is for Winforms.

Short summary:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern UInt32 SendMessage
    (IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, UInt32 wParam, UInt32 lParam);

internal const int BCM_FIRST = 0x1600; //Normal button
internal const int BCM_SETSHIELD = (BCM_FIRST + 0x000C); //Elevated button

static internal void AddShieldToButton(Button b)
{
    b.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
    SendMessage(b.Handle, BCM_SETSHIELD, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

---

### Update

[This](http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/uac-shield-icon-in-wpf) will give you direct access to the correct icon and it works in WPF directly.

```
BitmapSource shieldSource = null;

if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
{
    SHSTOCKICONINFO sii = new SHSTOCKICONINFO();
    sii.cbSize = (UInt32) Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHSTOCKICONINFO));

    Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(SHGetStockIconInfo(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_SHIELD,
        SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON | SHGSI.SHGSI_SMALLICON,
        ref sii));

    shieldSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        sii.hIcon,
        Int32Rect.Empty, 
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    DestroyIcon(sii.hIcon);
}
else
{
    shieldSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Shield.Handle,
        Int32Rect.Empty, 
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
```

p/Invoke Signatures can be found [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetStockIconInfo.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! [Am I doing something wrong?](https://i.imgur.com/2fgMfBt.png)

Comment: It looks like you are missing the class definitions for the p/invoke signature.  If you follow the link at the bottom for the signatures you will find more links labeled "User-Defined Types" with the names that match the classes you are missing.  You just need to add those classes and enumerations to your project.

Comment: Works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution: WPF Controls support nesting

```
        <Button Height="30" Width="200">
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="ImagePath"/>
                <Label Content="Label"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Button>
```

Comment: It works but I'm not 100% satisfied. Thank you for introducing me into a WPF item I didn't knew yet. I like this answer because it's 100% XAML but I don't accept it as an answer because It doesn't adjust to the Windows Resource and thus to the Windows Design Guideline (My Icon might be a bit bigger or smaller than original windows buttons). Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Very simple example adding a small shield icon and button text from code.
 The button should be added to XAML with the name "OkButton".

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadImage(
        IntPtr hinst,
        string lpszName,
        uint uType,
        int cxDesired,
        int cyDesired,
        uint fuLoad);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var image = LoadImage(IntPtr.Zero, "#106", 1, SystemInformation.SmallIconSize.Width, SystemInformation.SmallIconSize.Height, 0);
        var imageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(image, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        // Set button content from code
        var sp = new StackPanel
        {
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
        };
        sp.Children.Add(new Image { Source = imageSource, Stretch = Stretch.None });
       sp.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "OK", Margin = new Thickness(5, 0, 0, 0) });
        OkButton.Content = sp;
    }
```

Comment: Works great with few minor modifications - `SystemInformation.SmallIconSize.Width => (int)SystemParameters.SmallIconWidth` and  `SystemInformation.SmallIconSize.Height => (int)SystemParameters.SmallIconHeight` to avoid referencing Winforms, and I've stored the ImageSource as a property to load once and bind to. thanks!